# How to test mongoid scopes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mongoid

I defined the following User class with scopes :

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include Mongoid::Search

  # SCOPES
  scope :all_admins, where( role: :admin)
  scope :recents, order_by(created_at: :desc)
  scope :olders, order_by(created_at: :asc)

  field :role, type: Symbol
end
```

If I use the following rspec test :

```
describe 'scopes' do
  let(:admin1)            { Fabricate(:admin) }
  let(:admin2)               { Fabricate(:admin) }

  describe 'recents' do
    it 'should return the admins from most recent to older' do
      User.all_admins.recents.should eq([admin1, admin2])
    end
  end
end
```

I get the following fail message :

```
got: #<Mongoid::Criteria
  selector: {"role"=>:admin},
  options:  {:sort=>{"created_at"=>-1}},
  class:    User,
  embedded: false>
```

So how could I test this scope ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongoid lazy loads, do:

```
User.all_admins.recents.to_a.should eq([admin1, admin2])
```

Side notes:

- you should create your scopes as lambdas, it will soon be the norm with Rails4
- I got issues with symbol type in mongo (during migrations), I'd rather use strings
- I'm pretty sure your test will fail since your objects are not created in db (`let` is not evaluated until it's called, replace with `let!`)

Comment: I'm wondering if there isn't an overhead with having scopes as lambdas, even when not necessary. Have you seen anything related to this point on the subject, by any chance ?

Comment: Great : to_a did the job. let! also took part of the solution, because the objects are not created with let.